# Correct Use of MBTiles PHP Script

Tags: web-mapping, php, mbtiles

I have installed the OSGeo4W web server tools on a Server 2008 machine, and I would like to serve MBTiles to Leaflet.  I have tried these:

[Zverik's mbtiles-php](https://github.com/Zverik/mbtiles-php)

[Infostream's mbtiles-php fork](https://github.com/infostreams/mbtiles-php/)

The required PHP files and `.htaccess` were placed in a directory under `\htdocs` and Apache happily serves files from there.  However, I am unable to form any URL that retrieves tiles.  Firebug shows a '200 OK' on the tile request, but no content.

Given that the mbtiles database and the script reside in a directory called 'mbtiles', can anyone inspect the scripts and explain how to properly form the URL?  A proper `L.tileLayer` string for Leaflet would also be accepted.

Also, any other minimal configuration solution (that will run on the OSGeo4W install) that will serve my .mbtiles to Leaflet would be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 'mbtiles' as the directory, the correct URL to get tiles with Leaflet js is:

```
.../mbtiles/[filename without extension]/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

As a side note for anyone attempting to use these on an OSGeo4W install, you may need to `AllowOverride`  in `httpd.conf` and uncomment `extension=php_gd2.dll` in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to try this project:

https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php/

It is very easy to install and comes with sample viewers (Leaflet, OpenLayers, OL3, Google Maps API, etc) - presenting JavaScript source code.

The server supports also OGC WMTS - so the maps can be opened in QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop.

Here is a live demo: http://tileserver.maptiler.com/